# Why does my first javascript stop when I add another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am fairly new to JavaScript so I am not 100% sure to why it's behaving this way.

If I only have my loadData.js it's working fine but as soon as I add main.js to the html document it seems to skip loadData.js or just ignore it all together and I have no idea why.

I know that getData works I tried printing out the data without the main.js in the picture and it worked just fine.
Again it seems like it just skips using it as soon as I add main.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DummyPage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Please Select A Item</p>
            <select id="itemSelect">
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="mainBackground">
        <a id="myBtn" href="#" class="helmButtonStyle" onclick="getData()"></a>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="/js/loadData.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

loadData

```
function getData() {
    console.log("Hej");
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:53209/api/items', function (data) {
        var html = '';
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            html += '<option = value"' + data[i].Name + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>'; 
        }
        // console.log(html);
        $('itemSelect').append(html);
    });
}
```

main.js

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and the css
https://hastebin.com/papekiyuse.css

Comment: You likely have an error in your `main.js` file. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: The `script` elements either go inside the `head` or inside the `body`, not inside `html`.

Comment: I checked and the console doesnt put out any errors and oh yeah, the main.js works with and without the loadData.js but loadData doesnt work with main.js but it does work without it, and thanks for the tip angel

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `myBtn` has an `onclick` attribute which calls `getData`, but then in your `main.js`, you assign something *else* to `btn.onclick`. So, when the button is clicked, only the *second* `onclick` runs:

```js
function getData() {
  console.log('getting data');
}
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log('onclick');
}
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" href="#" class="helmButtonStyle" onclick="getData()">click me</a>
```

Easy solution: don't use inline listeners (they're bad practice anyway), and don't assign to `.onclick`, because those overwrite each other. Instead, use `addEventListener` to attach listeners properly using Javascript. `addEventListener` allows for more than one listener to be triggered from an event at a time:

In your `loadData`:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', getData);
function getData() {
// ...
```

In `main.js`:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

And remove the `onclick="getData()"` attribute from the HTML.

Also, in `main.js`, you also might consider using `querySelector` (which returns a single element) rather than using `getElementsByClassName` (which returns a collection): instead of

```
span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

you can use

```
span = document.querySelector('.close');
```

It's a bit more appropriate, and less unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Oh wow! Of course! I totally forgot they could overwrite each other! That makes so much sense now! And I was so confused, thinking that.. Inlining listeners, this feels so wrong, thanks for clearing that up! +1

Comment: While you're here, got any good YouTuber who teaches good practices with JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know youtube tutorials, sorry, everything I've learned is from a mishmash of Google, MDN, SO, and practice :P

Comment: That's what I am going for, I was just curious if there was a `Super javaScripter` on that platform, anyways, I keep getting a error about const btn `saying redeclaration of const btn`

Comment: Either put everything on the top level as it is now, and only define `btn` once, or put both scripts into an IIFE so they have their own scope. Another option would be to combine the text of both scripts into one script.

Comment: using var fixed it but now I am battleing a reference error for the event, I shall read on Google

Comment: Nvm forgot the event parameter :sigh: XD